# PHP Function to Reorder Array

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a PHP function to move an array key/value pair and make it to become the first element in the array.

Basically, I will like to convert

```
Array
(
    [a] => rose
    [b] => tulip
    [c] => dahlia
    [d] => peony
    [e] => magnolia
)
```

to

```
Array
(
    [c] => dahlia
    [a] => rose
    [b] => tulip
    [d] => peony
    [e] => magnolia
)
```

To clarify, the aim is to pick one specific key/value pair and move it to become the first indexed while keeping the rest of the order intact.

So in this case, I am looking for something like

```
$old_array = Array
    (
        [a] => rose
        [b] => tulip
        [c] => dahlia
        [d] => peony
        [e] => magnolia
    );
$new_array = some_func($old_array, 'c');
```

In $new_array, 'c' should be first in the list.

Any ideas on code for 'some_func()'?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Moving array element to top in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312879/moving-array-element-to-top-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may helpful to you :

```
function myfun($ar,$key){
    if (array_key_exists($key,$ar)) {
        $arr_tmp = array($key => $ar[$key]);
        unset($ar[$key]);
        return $arr_tmp + $ar;        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to put one element to first, then you could do:

```
function some_func($array, $key) {
   $tmp = array($key => $array[$key]);
   unset($array[$key]);
   return $tmp + $array;
}
```

Comment: At the risk of appearing to want to be fed everything, I don't have any sort logic apart from simply wanting to pass a key and have that key (plus associated value) move to the first index position. Can you help with that?

Comment: @Dayo I wrote the `some_func` for your requirement :)

Comment: PHP's sort algorithm is not stable, so using it isn't very trivial for this case. You'd have to index every element before sorting so that you could preserve order. A non-sort answer is likely to be the most efficient.

Comment: You should check for key If key is not exist then it will add key at first position but value will be not available.

Comment: @xdazz Thanks for the modified version. It is similar to Mahesh's answer which I accepted as it came earlier.

Answer (score 1):

```
function some_func($arr, $key) {
    $val = $arr[$key];
    unset($arr[$key]);
    return array_merge(array($key => $val), $arr);
}
```

[**See it on codepad**](http://codepad.org/DyudyH1g)