# Finding entry in array and putting it first or swapping with the first array entry

Tags: php

I have a PHP array full of arrays and what I want to do is search through this array for the chosen entry and swap it with the first entry in the array if that makes sense...

So for my example below I have chosen Penny so I would like her to either go before Bob or swap places with Bob.

My array looks like this:

```
$people = array(
array('Bob', 'Wilson'),
array('Jill', 'Thompson'),
array('Penny', 'Smith'),
array('Hugh', 'Carr')
);
```

I have tried using array_search but I don't think I am doing it correctly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312879/moving-array-element-to-top-in-php

Comment: Its possible logically but what have you tried ? you need help on making logic for that ?

Comment: You can’t use array_search for that, because that would only find something if you directly used an array containing the two strings 'Penny' and 'Smith' as search parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for ($i = count($array) - 1; $i > 0; $i--) {
    if ($array[$i][0] == $first_name) { // Or by whatever you want to search? in_array...?
        $searched_array = array_splice($array, $i, 1);
        array_unshift($array, $searched_array[0]);
    }
}
```

This is for prepending. If you want to swap, see the answer of @IAmNotProcrastinating

Answer (score 1):

```
function swap (&$ary,$fromIndex,$toIndex=0)
{
    $temp=$ary[$toIndex];
    $ary[$toIndex]=$ary[$fromIndex];
    $ary[$fromIndex]=$temp;
}
foreach ($elements as $key => $element) {
    /* do the search, get the $key and swap */
}
```