# complicate array push to the first index

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have multidimensional array which is create like

```
$column = array( 
"person#1"=> array ("name"=>"Leon" , "Age"=>"19" ),
"person#2"=> array ("name"=>"Gary" , "Age"=>"31" ),
"person#3"=> array ("name"=>"May" , "Age"=>"25" )
)
```

Now, what I want is to push something like

```
"person#4"=> array ("name"=>"Tony" , "Age"=>"28" )
```

to the first place of array column.

I had look into

```
array_unshift($column, array("person#1"=> array ("name"=>"Tony" , "Age"=>"28" ));
```

it did replace the array and variable with my array, but always indexed with '0' and not `person#4` as expect

Comment: Sorry that I didn't quite follow your question. Do you mean that you want to put `person#4` before `person#1`, or do you want to replace `person#1` as `person#4`?

Comment: I wanna put it before person#1 without index it to '0'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`array_merge()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$column = array(
"person#1"=> array ("name"=>"Leon" , "Age"=>"19" ),
"person#2"=> array ("name"=>"Gary" , "Age"=>"31" ),
"person#3"=> array ("name"=>"May" , "Age"=>"25" )
);

$column = array_merge(array( "person#4" => array ("name" => "Tony" , "Age" => "28" )), $column);

var_dump($column);
?>
```

Shows:

```
array(4) {
  ["person#4"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "Tony"
    ["Age"]=>
    string(2) "28"
  }
  ["person#1"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "Leon"
    ["Age"]=>
    string(2) "19"
  }
  ["person#2"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "Gary"
    ["Age"]=>
    string(2) "31"
  }
  ["person#3"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "May"
    ["Age"]=>
    string(2) "25"
  }
}
```

Comment: @Leon Armstrong , cheers. But there is an option of **w0rldart**'s version with `$column = array("person#4" => array ("name" => "Tony" , "Age" => "28" )) + $column;`. Works same (not fully tested though).

Comment: I think i just follow your way , Its easier to understand

Answer (score 3):

Why not do a simple `$new_person + $column` ?

Comment: Definately better, than mine)

Comment: Look like your code is cleaner , but is there a way to push person#4 to the first of stack?

Comment: @LeonArmstrong this will conserve the key name and it's value when moving it to the beginning http://stackoverflow.com/a/5312907/971392

Comment: @LeonArmstrong Just reverse the plus order: `$new_person + $column`. http://3v4l.org/L1VtP

Comment: oh now I realize what @CORRUPT was suggesting, tnx Passer