# Array_splice "cut and paste" an element

Tags: php

I have an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [field_id] => 1
            [field_name] => NO_INSCRIPTION
            [order_number] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [field_id] => 2
            [field_name] => NO_ADDENDA
            [order_number] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [field_id] => 3
            [field_name] => CODE_LANGUE
            [order_number] => 2
        )

    [3] => ARRAY
        (
            [field_id] => 7
            [field_name] => TEXTE
            [order_number] => 3
        )
)
```

I want to **move** the 4th element to the second position so it's

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [field_id] => 1
            [field_name] => NO_INSCRIPTION
            [order_number] => 0
        )

    [1] => ARRAY
        (
            [field_id] => 7
            [field_name] => TEXTE
            [order_number] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [field_id] => 2
            [field_name] => NO_ADDENDA
            [order_number] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [field_id] => 3
            [field_name] => CODE_LANGUE
            [order_number] => 2
        )

)
```

I tried `array_splice` with the same function using

```
array_splice($arr, 1, 0, $arr[3]);
```

But it's returning something weird and it also keeps a copy of the 3rd element

I know this can be done using `array_slice` but may be there's a more elegant, readable way of achieving this? Hopefully with a one liner built-in PHP function.

Comment: `array_splice` won't copy associative keys; it will just insert values with the next numeric key.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moving array element to top in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312879/moving-array-element-to-top-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't try to do this in one line. Splice the desired element out, then splice it back into the desired position:

```php
$extracted = array_splice($arr, 3, 1);
array_splice($arr, 1, 0, $extracted[0]);
```

One-liners are nice when the resulting code is clean and easy to understand, but with an operation like `array_splice()` where the array is modified in place, the results can be very difficult to wrap your head around. If you really want a one-liner, that's what functions are for:

```php
function moveArrayElement(&$array, $from, $to) {
    $extracted = array_splice($array, $from, 1);
    array_splice($array, $to, 0, $extracted);
}

moveArrayElement($arr, 3, 1);
```

Comment: I edited the question with sample data, when I try your example with the sample data it returns something strange.

Comment: @RobertSinclair You'll need to be more clear about what that "something strange" is. I can't debug something that I can't reproduce, and this code works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: you code does not work perfectly fine with an associative array in the sample data i posted. I'll post the result in the question so it's readable

Comment: @RobertSinclair I just noticed the problem. It's part of `array_splice()`'s functionality at play. I just applied a fix to my solution. Try that.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this as a one-liner by combining two calls to [`array_splice`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php), the first which extracts the value you want to move, and the second which re-inserts it. This takes advantage of the fact that `array_splice` modifies the array in place and returns the extracted value:

```
$from = 3;
$to = 1;
array_splice($arr, $to, 0, array_splice($arr, $from, 1));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [field_id] => 1
            [field_name] => NO_INSCRIPTION
            [order_number] => 0
        )    
    [1] => Array
        (
            [field_id] => 7
            [field_name] => TEXTE
            [order_number] => 3
        )    
    [2] => Array
        (
            [field_id] => 2
            [field_name] => NO_ADDENDA
            [order_number] => 1
        )    
    [3] => Array
        (
            [field_id] => 3
            [field_name] => CODE_LANGUE
            [order_number] => 2
        )    
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/WjEgE)

Comment: I actually think @B.Fleming answer is better - the points they make in terms of readability and functions (with meaningful names!) are very valid. Personally I would accept that one.

Comment: Agreed, but I just put the following as comments right above it which makes it readable also "You can do this as a one-liner by combining two calls to array_splice, the first which extracts the value you want to move, and the second which re-inserts it. "

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different sorting functions. In your case you want to look at [natcasesort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natcasesort.php)

```
<?php
$r = ['a', 'c', 'B', 'd'];

natcasesort($r);

print_r($r);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [2] => B
    [1] => c
    [3] => d
)
```

Comment: thank you, i'll keep it in mind. in my case it's an associative array, i used the letters as an example only

Comment: You should update your question accordingly with a relevant example.

Comment: sure, will do now

Comment: Most likely [asort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) will handle sorting by value for an associatively keyed array

Comment: The question isn't really about sorting at all, so this answer is inappropriate.

Comment: @Nick, it certainly started out as a sorting question as originally posed.

Comment: Actually, no, you interpreted it as being a sorting question. OP stated they wanted to move an array element from one index to another, they never said anything about sorting.

Comment: The example originally provided suggested sortation.  Once I requested an edit with actual data, it was clear that sortation was not the issue.  At any rate, I agree with your solution so enjoy your points.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `array_sort` it might be the best in this case

```
$base = [
    0 => "a",
    1 =>  "c",
    2 =>  "d",
    3 =>  "b"
];

$replacement = [1 => $base[3], 3 => $base[1]];
$res = array_replace($base, $replacement);

print_r($res);
```

result will be like this

```
Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => d [3] => c )
```

Comment: i will look at it again

Comment: @Nick i update the answer please check it again

Comment: @Nick i know that i update it before i use `array_replace` now to replace two-element as he mentions